# C# Winform The process still on Windows Task list manager after close programme

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, kill-process

why The process still on Windows Task list manager after close programme ?

i use login Form.cs

```
 [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Login());
        }
```

after the user succesuly login, i redirect to another Masterpage

```
 this.Hide();
            Main_Usr oMainUsr = new Main_Usr();                    
            oMainUsr.Visible = true;
```

my pseudo master page like this:

```
public Main_Usr()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.IsMdiContainer = true;
        }
```

when i close the masterpage, The process still on Windows Task list manager.
But when i close the login page, it kill the process on Windows Task list manager.

is that mean because i just hide le login page ? 
must i close all window to realy quit/kill the process ?

Thanks you in advance,
Stev

Comment: you just need to close login form(note: form not page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In winforms process will be killed, when main application form is closed. Main application form is one specified in Application.Run call. In your case it is Login form:

```
Application.Run(new Login());
```

To close form you should call `Close` method. When you call `Hide` or set `Visibility` to false, form stays in memory. It just becomes hidden from user.

So, to achieve desired functionality you should change main application form to Main_Usr:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Main_Usr()); // change main form
}
```

Then subscribe to `Load` event of Main_User form. And in the event handler do following:

```
private void Main_User_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var loginForm = new Login())
    {
        Hide(); // hide main form

        if (loginForm.ShowDialog() != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Close(); // close main form and kill process
            return;
        }

        Show(); // show main form if user logged in successfully 
    }
}
```

UPDATE: You can do this all in Main method, like this way

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    using(var loginForm = new Login())
         if (loginForm.ShowDialog() != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
             return;
    Application.Run(new Main_Usr()); // change main form
}
```

but usually I don't hide main form and show it below login form. So, in this case you should use `Load` event handler. It's up to you.

BTW there is no masterpages and pages in winforms. This all is for ASP.NET. Here you have forms :)
Also consider naming like LoginForm, MainForm etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the application message loop is associated with your `Login` form (`Application.Run(new Login())` does this), so you need to close the form which started the application to end the process.

Alternatively, you could just call `LoginForm.Show()`, before `Application.Run`, store credentials somewhere and then call `Application.Run(new Main_Usr)`

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.
' [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Login oLogin = new Login();
            oLogin.Show();
            Application.Run(new Main_Usr());
        }'
but it open main page before login procedure

Comment: Take a look on lazyberezovsky's answer, specifically on Update section, there is a piece if code, showing how it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Login` is the last form of the application to close, you load `Main_User` only after that - even if `Login` is hidden it's still actually there. Windows Forms applications are by default configured to exit when the last form closes.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Hide()
```

doesn`t kill the window.

So it remains hidden and process remains in memory.
    this.Close() closes the window and removes its object from memory.

It is better to do something like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    var l = new Login();
    l.ShowDialog();
    if(l.Passed)
       Application.Run(new Login());
}
```

And implement Passed property inside login window.

By the way, do you have any multithreading inside?
It is another source of errors of this type.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, but i can't get l.Passed

Comment: You have your Login form, just add `public bool Passed{get;set;}` and set it true on success login.

Answer (score 0):

i found it, i just use the dizlog.

```
 [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Login oLogin = new Login();
            oLogin.ShowDialog();
            Application.Run(new Main_Usr());
        }
```

Comment: In this case Main_Usr will be shown always. Whether login was valid or not. Check if login was successful before showing Main_User

Answer (score 0):

i follow code the @lazyberezovsky and add this on my Login.cs

```
  private void simpleButton_Valider_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
       .....
          DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                    return;
       .....
   }
```