# C# app stays in task manager after closing

Tags: c#

I'm testing my C# app from the `bin/Release` the app works perfectly but whenever I close the application the name still appears in the task manager, and if I try to open it again it opens and another process still shows in the task manager
So if I open the app 10 times, 10 processes will show in the task manager.

I changed my code to close the form from this.Hide() to this.Close() but the problem stayed :(

what might be the problem.
I'm not using threads in my application, do I need to post parts of my code?

Edit:
this is the login form (form 1)

```
if ((aun.Text != "") && (apw.Text != ""))
{
    try
    {
        ConnectionInfo.con.Open();
        string un, pw;
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select un,pw from creden where creden.un=@un", ConnectionInfo.con);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@un", aun.Text);
        SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

        dr2.Read();

        un = dr2.GetString(0);
        pw = dr2.GetString(1);

        dr2.Close();
        if ((un == aun.Text) && (pw == apw.Text))
        {
            dashboard d1 = new dashboard(aun.Text);
            this.Close();d1.Show();

        }//end if similar credentials entered
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("لقد أدخلت كلمة بيانات خاطئة الرجاء التأكد ");
        }//end if wrong pw is entered
    }//end try
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("هنالك خطأ في اسسم المستخدم");
    }
    finally 
    {
        ConnectionInfo.con.Close();
    }

}//end if
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("الرجاء أدخل جميع البيانات");
}//end else
```

this is the second form

```
public dashboard(string x)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    label3.Text = x;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Products pdts = new Products(label3.Text);
    this.Close();
    pdts.Show();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Capital c = new Capital(label3.Text);
    this.Close();
    c.Show();
}
```

Comment: Yes, without your code, it's hard to tell where the problem is. I guess there's still another thread running.

Comment: Applications do *not* stay alive after closing. You don't need to write *any* code to close your application. By default, closing the main form closes the application as well. If you felt the need to call `Hide()` or `Close()` it means that you modified the original code. Please post your code

Comment: I posted my code above

Comment: Show your program.cs and your login logic. A WinForms application exits when the startup form is closed. My guess is that you keep the startup form active.

Comment: `Application.Exit();`?

Comment: but the startup form is the login, should I add a pre-form or something like that??

Comment: If you create background threads for processing, please make sure they are marked as `Thread.IsBackground = true`.  That ensures that the thread is free to be terminated when you close the application.

Comment: @zozi Look at [that link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312364/c-sharp-winform-the-process-still-on-windows-task-list-manager-after-close-progr)

Comment: @OrkunBekar u saved my day, tnx